# Probability terminology

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions, terminology

This is strictly a low-level terminology question.  If I have a probability space $\Omega$ and a measurable space $S$, then a random variable $X:\Omega\rightarrow S$ gives rise via pushforward to a probability distribution on $S$.  I want to assume that every probability distribution on $S$ arises in this way.  Is there a name for that condition on the pair $(\Omega,S)$ or do I need to make one up?

Comment: If $S$ is an uncountable Polish space, this is equivalent to the underlying probability space being atomless.

Comment: It is common to work with the space of probability measures on a Polish space. Perhaps what you are trying to describe is some continuous injection from the space of probability measures in $\Omega$ to $S$.

Comment: I would just make it up without doing an extensive literature search. It is quite likely that *someone called it something somewhere at some time* but it is also likely that then *someone else called it something else  somewhere else at some other time*. If it is not mentioned in any standard book like Feller, Doob, etc., then I wouldn't bother to search for it anywhere beyond.

Comment: @Jimbo It is the other way around: $\Omega$ should be sufficiently large (or $S$ sufficiently small), so we are talking about *surjection* rather than injection when we go from something $\Omega$ related to something $S$ related.